# Favicons vanished on multiple sites but no code was changed

Tags: html, dom, favicon, modx

- Happened across nearly all of our 7 sites.
- No code in that area was changed
- Effects all browsers / different users / different pcs
- Purged site cache / Cloudflare cache
- If you view source and click the favicon url they are there
- Presumed might be a browser update / have effected others but could not find a common / current reference to anything like that.
- Weirdly defaults to that of our host (Modx cloud) but their favicon is not mentioned in the DOM

Any suggestions, samples below:

http://www.ceramicsexpousa.com/

http://www.foam-expo.com/

http://www.spacetechexpo.com/

http://www.adhesivesandbondingexpo.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing `<subtitle style="display: none;">Home</subtitle>` from the head section of your template. I don't believe that is a valid tag for the head and seems to be causing the rest of the tags in the head section to be rendered as if they are in the body section.

Comment: Thank you sir.  tag was added as part of a search app - that had escaped my attention.  your answer worked.